# codeigniter getting database after login

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using https://github.com/firoz-ahmad-likhon a codeigniter user role system.

I am working on an app what has a database, however, I want the user information to be stored on another database. When the user logs in the user database will return that name of the database where the data is stored

//something like this

```
protected function setUser()
{
    $account = $this->CI->db- 
    >get_where("accounts", array("id" 
    => $this->user->account_id))- 
    >row(0);
    $_SESSION['db_name'] = $account;

    var_dump($_SESSION['db_name']);

  
.....................
return true;
}
```

the var_dump give this

object(stdClass)#27 (6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["company"]=> string(10) "management" ["database"]=> string(21) "management_qpuv0o2y3r" ["user_limit"]=> string(1) "1" ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=> NULL

Then I want this code to set the active database to  "management_qpuv0o2y3r".

p.s. this code is in a library.

Comment: please read on CI docs - [Manually Connecting to a database](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html#manually-connecting-to-a-database)]

Answer (score 0):

I have managed more or less to sort out this issue.

in the setUser function I use the code below;

```
//get account details from user database
$account = $this->CI->db->get_where("management_users.accounts", array("id" => $this->user->account_id))->row(0);    
//set session details
$this->CI->session->set_userdata(array('db_name'=>$account));
 
//set database   
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->db->db_select($account->database);
```

Then in the main controller which in my case is the MY_Controller , in the constructor I use something like this

```
$CI = get_instance();
if(isset($CI->session->userdata['db_name']->database)){
    $CI->db->db_select($CI->session->userdata['db_name']->database);
}else{
    // return redirect();
}
```

This seems to be doing the trick for me know